# How do I add a body to a POST request in JavaScript using a promise?

Tags: javascript, post, promise, async-await, http-get

I have the following function that works fine for a GET request:

```
function httpGet(options) {
return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

  
  const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    let returnData = '';

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      returnData += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
    });

    response.on('error', (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
  request.end();
}));
}
```

Using the following options this works fine:

```
let path = `/1/indexes/combined-faq-directions?query=${location}&typoTolerance=false&getRankingInfo=true&optionalWords=${location}`;
    
var options = {
    host: 'YQRKWVXBWV-1.algolianet.com',
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    "X-Algolia-API-Key": "APIKEYXXXX",
    "X-Algolia-Application-ID": "IDXXX"
    }
};
```

But I'm now trying to do a POST to a different URL using the same format. Through postman I can see this works fine but I can't seem to get it into the correct format for my promise.

```
var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'hostname': 'api.airtable.com',
  'path': '/v0/appasoP3zaNL9k8Pj/Analytics',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer keyxxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': 'brw=brw9wuY1b9RmtTl1q'
  },
  'maxRedirects': 20
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});

var postData = JSON.stringify({"records":[{"fields":{"RoomNo":"Room 6"}}]});

req.write(postData);

req.end();
```

I have tried this to adjust it but getting an error ERR_STREAM_WHITE_AFTER_END

```
let path = `v0/appasoP3zaNL9k8Pj/Analytics`;

var options = {
  host: "api.airtable.com",
  port: 443,
  path: path,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer keyxxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};

var postData = JSON.stringify({ records: [{ fields: { RoomNo: "Room 6" } }] });

async function asyncCall() {
  const response = await httpGet(options, postData);

  console.log(response);
}

asyncCall();

function httpGet(options, postData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
      response.setEncoding("utf8");
      let returnData = "";

      response.on("data", (chunk) => {
        returnData += chunk;
      });

      response.on("end", () => {
        resolve(JSON.parse(returnData));
      });

      response.on("error", (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
      if (postData) {
        request.write(postData);
      }
    });
    request.end();
  });
}
```

I think I'm very close but just can't figure out the syntax. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're not sending a `Content-Length` header

Comment: Regarding your last snippet, you'd need to move the `request.end()` call inside the callback as well, after the `if` statement with the `request.write(…)`.

Comment: thanks for the help. I moved request.end inside but my request does not complete. Did some reading on Content-Length but looks like it isnt required in the postman version?

Comment: I'd expect postman to automatically set it. You don't want to count bytes yourself when you write some body.